# Why python dictonary gives me Keyerror?

Tags: python

I am reading excel file and creating dictionary using following code in file a.py.

```
productNo = int(worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, 1))
    print "Product No :" + str(productNo)
    products[productNo] = {}

    while curr_cell < num_cells:
        curr_cell += 1
        header =  str(worksheet.cell_value(0, curr_cell))


        # Cell Types: 0=Empty, 1=Text, 2=Number, 3=Date, 4=Boolean, 5=Error, 6=Blank
        cell_type = worksheet.cell_type(curr_row, curr_cell)
        #print '    ',curr_cell,' <-> ', cell_type
        cell_value = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
        if cell_type == 0 or cell_type == 6:
            products[productNo][header] = ""
        if cell_type == 1:
            #products[productNo] = {header :cell_value}
            products[productNo][header] = cell_value
        elif cell_type == 2:
            cell_value = int(cell_value)
            print "Header " + header
            products[productNo][header] = cell_value
        elif cell_type == 3:
            products[productNo] = {header :cell_value}
        elif cell_type == 4:
            products[productNo] = {header :cell_value}
```

In file main.py I am calling above written code  (in function) and catalouge.readExcel('D:/Personal/CatalogNo_1134.xls', products) by passing variable products as dictionary.

When dump it I am getting all keys and values.

```
print "Dump " + str(products)

    print  products.keys()

    print products['28852']['ProductNo']
    print products['28852']['Style']


Dump {28852: {'Category': u'Party Wear', 'Style': u'Designer', 'ProductNo': 28852, 'ProductGroup': u'Salwar Kameez', 'CatalogNo': 1134, 'ProductType': u'Salwar Kameez', 'SubCategoryDefinition': '', 'Fabric': u'Faux Georgette', 'MinWebPrice': 3395, 'Description': u'Capture The Exuberance Of Womanhood In Its Full Glory That Will Bring Out Your Fragility And Femininity. Genuine Magnificence Will Come Out Through The Dressing Style With This Off White Faux Georgette Salwar Kameez. The Appealing Lace|Resham Work Through The Attire Is Awe-Inspiring.', 'OptionOfSleeves': '', 'Rate/FreeSize': 2095, 'XLRate': 0, 'GenericName': u'Dress Material', 'SizeAvailable': u'Not Applicable', 'MaxLengthCholi': '', 'ItemTag': u'Enigmatic Off White Salwar Kameez', 'SubCategory': u'Other - Party Wear', 'Description of Blouse/Choli/Bottom': u'Paired With A Matching Bottom', 'Colour': u' Off White', 'Work': u'Lace|Resham', 'ExpressQty': 0, 'Occasion': u'Christmas,Diwali,Eid,Festival,Kitty Party,Mehendi,Navratri,Party Wear,Sangeet,Wedding', 'Weight': 1, 'Description of Dupatta': u'Comes With A Matching Dupatta', 'DeliveryDays': 8}, 28853: {...}}
```

keys are

```
[28852, 28853, 28854, 28855, 28856, 28857, 28858, 28859, 28860, 28861, 28862, 28863]
```

When I access it using products['28852']

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    print products['28852']['ProductNo']
KeyError: '28852'
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `'28852'` and not just `28852`? (string v/s number)

Comment: Thanks Sanjay for prompt response. productNo = int(worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, 1))
        print "Product No :" + str(productNo)
        products[productNo] = {}

Comment: You are only making it harder for us and yourself. First please include your code, and then make sure that you get the value you expect from worksheet before you try to use it (just print it).

Comment: It is number.  I tried access it by no = '28852' and then print products[no]['ProductNo']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing `str` `28852` while the key is integer. Please access with `28852`.

Comment: Got it. it is Working . Thanks you very much Lafada.  Thanks All for your prompt response.